# How is this the present perfect continuous?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, present-perfect, perfect-continuous

> Pakistan has been slow to embrace the revolution that is the internet.

According to present perfect continuous tense, *has/have + been + istform + ing* is used, but in this case *slow* is used. I am  confused. Please help.

Comment: Present perfect continuous would be *Pakistan **has been being** slow to embrace change*, a form which in fact native speakers would very rarely use in this context.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the present perfect continuous. It is the ordinary present perfect of *BE* followed by the adjective *slow*.

> Pakistan is beautiful/peaceful/mountainous/slow ...
>   Pakistan was beautiful/peaceful/mountainous/slow ...
>   Pakistan has been beautiful/peaceful/mountainous/slow ...

*Slow* may take a complement in the form of an infinitival phrase designating an action: the entity modified by *slow* is thus said to perform that action *slowly*:

> John has been slow to finish his essay. ... *He has been finishing his essay slowly.*
>   Mary is slow to take offense. ... *She takes offense slowly.*
>   Pakistan has been slow to embrace the internet. ... *It has been embracing the internet slowly*.

The construction *slow to VERB* puts the focus on how slowly *VERB* is being performed.

Answer (score 0):

*Has been slow* is the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), not the [present perfect continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html).